# Calculate the work required (by external forces) to transport charge from its location on the figure to infinity.

Tags: physics

Three charges are located in the $x-y$ plane (see plot below), with $Q_1 = -6.00 μC$, $Q_2 = 2.00 μC$ and $Q_3 = 3.00 μC$. Note that the charges are located at grid intersections points.

Calculate the work required (by external forces) to transport $Q_3$ from its location on the figure to infinity.

[Image of Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNQ7C.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Use the conservation of energy.  Compute the potential energy of the system at the start and the end.  The difference is the work required.

Comment: I calculated the total electrostatic potential energy at the beginning to be -5.49×10-2 J. How do I go about finding the potential energy at the end since q3 is traveling to infinity?

Comment: The potential goes as $\frac 1r$, so $q3$ has no potential energy.  Just compute the potential between $q1$ and $q2$ to compare.  That is the point of the exercise.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes so much more sense.